# Do you have to specify a version tag to target features in Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

In the Flash Player if you need certain features you can use a compiler argument -swf-version=19. I think this makes sure that if a certain API was introduced the compiler will be sure to include it? It may also show an error message to visitors who do not have at least swf version 19?

If you are making an AIR app do you need to use -swf-version? Because in the application descriptor there is an XML namespace attribute that looks like it's doing the same thing,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/19.0">
```

I guess I'm confused on the relationship between swf-version and AIR version. In my AIR application I'm using -swf-version=19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to indicate swf-version.

For AIR version to swf-version conversion, you can see the `airsdk.xml` file of your AIR SDK, take this example of AIR 19 :

```
<airSdk xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/sdk/19.0">
    <applicationNamespaces>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/19.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>30</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/18.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>29</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>28</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>27</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/15.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>26</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>25</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/13.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>24</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>23</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.9</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>22</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.8</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>21</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.7</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>20</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>19</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.5</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>18</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>17</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.3</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>16</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.2</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>15</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>14</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>13</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.7</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>12</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>11</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>10</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>10</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>           
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5.3</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>10</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>           
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5.2</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>10</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>           
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5.1</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>10</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>           
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>10</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>           
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.1</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>10</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>           
        <versionMap>
            <descriptorNamespace>http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.0</descriptorNamespace>
            <swfVersion>10</swfVersion>
        </versionMap>
    </applicationNamespaces>

    <!-- ... -->

</airSdk>
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I'm confused by how your answer is worded... You *do* need to specify the lowest swf-version that you are targeting in AIR when you compile the swf in order to determine the min. runtime environment that your app will run it (assuming you are not using a captive runtime), otherwise the SDK will use the latest version available.... i.e. If you require the Air 20 runtime for the new `createVertexBufferForInstances` method, than `-swf-version=31`